# Input expression with summations in Wolfram Alpha

Tags: wolfram-alpha

Wolfram understand [this expression](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%282/n%29%2a%28sum%281,i=1%20to%20n%29%20%20%2b%20sum%28%284/n%29%2ai,i=1..n%29%20%2b%20sum%28%284/n%5E2%29%2ai%5E2,i=1..n%29%29) , but i need to do [the limit when n tends to infinity of that expression](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit%20of%20%282/n%29%2a%28sum%281,i=1%20to%20n%29%20%20%2b%20sum%28%284/n%29%2ai,i=1..n%29%20%2b%20sum%28%284/n%5E2%29%2ai%5E2,i=1..n%29%29,%20n%20tends%20to%20infinity%20) .

As you can see in the wolfram web itself, in the last link it fails to understand the query.

How can i do that?

Comment: At the bottom, there is an "expanded form" of that expression. You can directly read the limit off that.

Comment: Do you want to make WolframAlpha understand it or you understand it? Which one is your main goal? The limit can be computed by hand.

Comment: This question is fully **un-** selfcontained.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested in the comment, at the very bottom of the page (first link), you'll see "Expanded form". If you merely "click" on the expression, the page will open to [this page](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%284%2b24%20n%2b26%20n%5E2%29/%283%20n%5E2%29&lk=1&a=ClashPrefs_%2aMath-), where you'll find the limit of the expression stated explicitly:

Here's the limit (scroll down on the linked page to see it):

$$\lim_{n\to\pm\infty}\dfrac{4+24n+26n^2}{2n^2}=\dfrac{26}{3}\approx8.66667$$

Note that once you know the "expanded form" (or closed form) of the sum:

$$S(n) = \frac{4 + 24n + 26n^2}{3n^2},$$

Finding $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} S(n)$ is fairly straightforward: We can see this limit more readily if we simply divide the numerator and denominator by $n^2:$

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}S(n) = \large \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\frac{4}{n^2} + \frac{24}{n} + 26}{3} = \frac {26}{3}$$

Comment: two answers ;-) =1